# How to intercept a Custom Event when event name contains a dot?

Tags: javascript, events, stimulusjs

I'm trying to intercept an event from the stimulus-autocomplete library.

When I try to intercept the toggle event, it works fine.

```js
export default class extends Controller {
    //...
    toggle(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

I know try to intercept an event when user selects a new value.
[I read in documentation](https://github.com/afcapel/stimulus-autocomplete/blob/master/README.md):

> **autocomplete.change** fires when the users selects a new value from the autocomplete field. The event detail contains the value and textValue properties of the selected result.
>
> ...
>
> **toggle** fires when the results element is shown or hidden.

The dot is surprising. [I checked in the code source of the library](https://github.com/afcapel/stimulus-autocomplete/blob/019b7ded70b0e3f99ffaf686d508a5b76dc28356/src/autocomplete.mjs#L158). Yes, there is a dot.

```
 new CustomEvent("autocomplete.change", {
```

Ok, so I tried with a dot, but, during compilation, I have a syntax error on the dot.

```js
export default class extends Controller {
    autocomplete.change(event) {                 
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Nothing happen when I tried:

```js
export default class extends Controller {
    change(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Nothing happen when I tried with quotes. I mean, the log is always empty whatever I do.

```js
export default class extends Controller {
    'autocomplete.change'(event) {
        console.log(event); 
    }
}
```

How to intercept the custom event `autocomplete.change`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [solution on Hotwire](https://discuss.hotwire.dev/t/add-and-remove-eventlisteners/710). I have to add a listener on document.

```js
export default class extends Controller {
    
    connect() {
        document.addEventListener("autocomplete.change", this.autocomplete.bind(this))
    }

    autocomplete(event) {
       console.log(event)
    }
```